# Extracting parameters from URL with POST method

Tags: java, rest, post, spring-boot

I have something like this :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/prop")
public class PropController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Prop getProp(@ModelAttribute PropForm propForm) {
   //calling methods and stuff using propForm
}
}
```

My PropForm class :

```
@Data
public class PropForm {
            private  String att1; 
            private  String att2; 
            private  String att3;
}
```

Now I am calling this URL :

`http://localhost:8080/prop?att1=blabla&att2=blob&att3=test`

I want to extract the parameters from the URL and put them in my propForm.

I've tried replacing `@ModelAttribute` by `@RequestBody` and then by  `@RequestParam`. It's still not working, I always get a `NullPointerException` when running the application.

Please, note that I need to use POST method. I already have it working using GET method

Comment: I think you could try something like this @QueryParam("att1") String att1

Comment: How are you calling it and what are the details of this `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you controller and mapping is ok.
But the problem is you are expecting a post request in the mapping, and you are calling 
`http://localhost:8080/prop?att1=blabla&att2=blob&att3=test`

Now this will generate a **GET** request **Not Post**. You cannot send a post request using only url.

If you cant use a form for sending the request then you need to use any 3rd party to generate a POST request
like you can use  `jquery $.post()`

And also `att1` `att2` will not help unless you bind the object  with the model attribute.

Comment: Indeed, apparently it's just not possible. Thank you for explaining why.

Answer (score 1):

**FIRST** Make sure you have `getters` and `setters` in your `PropForm` class...

Then, you need to put into your model the Form entity:

```
model.put("NAME", propForm);
```

And declare method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Prop getProp(
    @ModelAttribute PropForm propForm
    @Valid @ModelAttribute("NAME") PropForm propForm) 
    //                     ^ you're missing the name!
{
     // do your stuff....


    return (Prop) propForm;
}
```

Comment: I do not have a view yet. And I'd like to use my PropForm class instead of individual attributes as att1, att2 and att3 are just examples, the list of attributes is quite long

Comment: Is it mandatory to have a view ? All I have is the URL, so I don't really know what to put in the name

Comment: what do you mean by model ?

Comment: [Check this link](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/understanding-spring-mvc-model-and-session-attributes/)

Comment: Thank you for the link, but apparently it isn't possible to do it. Thank you for you time.